# How to generate shapefiles for H3 hexagons in a particular area

Tags: shapefile, h3

I would like to generate shapefiles for [H3](https://github.com/uber/h3) hexagons in a specific geographic area. Particularly, I'm interested in the Bay Area with resolutions = 6, 7 and 9. How can I create the shapefiles for the hexagons covering this area?

I'm new to shapefiles or any other geographic data structures. I'm most comfortable with  python and R.

Answer (score 18):

The basic steps here are:

- Take a polygon of your desired area. A bounding box should work well.
- Use the `polyfill` method to fill the polygon with hexagons at the desired resolution.
- Loop over each hexagon and get the boundary with the `h3ToGeoBoundary` function.
- Put these boundaries into a GeoJSON file
- Use a converter like `ogr2ogr` to convert to a shapefile.

The Python bindings have not been released, and I'm not familiar with the R bindings, but the JavaScript version might look like this:

```
var h3 = require('h3-js');

var bbox = [
    [-123.308821530582, 38.28055644998254],
    [-121.30037257250085, 38.28055644998254],
    [-121.30037257250085, 37.242722073589164],
    [-123.308821530582, 37.242722073589164]
];

var hexagons = h3.polyfill(bbox, 6, true);

var geojson = {
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
        type: 'MultiPolygon',
        coordinates: hexagons.map(function toBoundary(hex) {
            return [h3.h3ToGeoBoundary(hex, true)];
        })
    }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(geojson));
```

and you'd use the script like this:

```
node bbox-geojson.js | ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" bbox-hexagons.shp /vsistdin/
```

Comment: Nice script. Thanks. Do you think there is any way to preserve the index as attributes for each polygon?

Comment: @loki - I believe you'd need to make a `FeatureCollection` of `Polygon` features, each of which can have an `id` and potentially `properties`

Comment: There is also this library, saving a lot of code https://github.com/uber/geojson2h3

Answer (score 8):

If you're looking for  solution in `R`, the [`h3jsr` package](https://github.com/obrl-soil/h3jsr) provides access to Uber's H3 library. The solution to your question can be done using the functions `h3jsr::polyfill()` and `h3jsr::h3_to_polygon`.

#### Reproducible example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(h3jsr)
library(sf)
library(sf)


# read the shapefile of the polygon area you're interested in
  nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE)

# projection
  nc <- st_transform(nc, crs = 4326)

# get the unique h3 ids of the hexagons intersecting your polygon at a given resolution
  nc_5 <- polyfill(nc, res = 5, simple = FALSE)

# pass the h3 ids to return the hexagonal grid
  hex_grid5 <- unlist(nc_5$h3_polyfillers) %>% h3_to_polygon(simple = FALSE)
```

This will return the polygons below:

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Any chance you can turn this into H3 for Python? I cannot reproduce with R as of today.

Answer (score 3):

Taking up John Stud's question here, because I've had the same 'problem'. In the following, I'll comment on how to read in a shapefile, hexagonize it with H3, and get a Hexagon geodataframe from it (and eventually save it as a shapefile).

**Reproducible example**

Let's get a shapefile for the US, e.g. [here](https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html) (I use the "cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip" one).

```
# Imports
import h3
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import shapely
from shapely.ops import unary_union
from shapely.geometry import mapping, Polygon

# Read shapefile
gdf = gpd.read_file("data/cb_2018_us_state_500k.shp")

# Get US without territories / Alaska + Hawaii
us = gdf[~gdf.NAME.isin(["Hawaii", "Alaska", "American Samoa", 
                         "United States Virgin Islands", "Guam",
                         "Commonwealth of the Northern Mariana Islands",
                         "Puerto Rico"])]

# Plot it
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
us.plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# Convert to EPSG 4326 for compatibility with H3 Hexagons
us = us.to_crs(epsg=4326)

# Get union of the shape (whole US)
union_poly = unary_union(us.geometry)

# Find the hexagons within the shape boundary using PolyFill
hex_list=[]
for n,g in enumerate(union_poly):
    if (n+1) % 100 == 0:
        print(str(n+1)+"/"+str(len(union_poly)))
    temp = mapping(g)
    temp['coordinates']=[[[j[1],j[0]] for j in i] for i in temp['coordinates']]  
    hex_list.extend(h3.polyfill(temp,res=5))

# Create hexagon data frame
us_hex = pd.DataFrame(hex_list,columns=["hex_id"])

# Create hexagon geometry and GeoDataFrame
us_hex['geometry'] = [Polygon(h3.h3_to_geo_boundary(x, geo_json=True)) for x in us_hex["hex_id"]]
us_hex = gpd.GeoDataFrame(us_hex)

# Plot the thing
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
us_hex.plot(ax=ax, cmap="prism")
plt.show()
```

[image]

The above plot has resolution "5" (https://h3geo.org/docs/core-library/restable/), I suggest you look at other resolutions, too, like 4:

[image]

Of course, that depends on the "zoom level", i.e., whether you're looking at entire countries or just cities or so.

And, of course, to answer the original question: You can save the resulting shapefile using

```
us_hex.to_file("us_hex.shp")
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified one from @nrabinowitz with separate polygons and index names:

```
var h3 = require('h3-js');

var bbox = [
    [-123.308821530582, 38.28055644998254],
    [-121.30037257250085, 38.28055644998254],
    [-121.30037257250085, 37.242722073589164],
    [-123.308821530582, 37.242722073589164]
];

var hexagons = h3.polyfill(bbox, 5, false);

var features = hexagons.map(function toBoundary(hex) {

var coords = h3.h3ToGeoBoundary(hex, true)
var feature = {"type": "Feature",
    "properties": {"name": hex},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [coords]}};

    return feature;
    });

console.log(JSON.stringify({
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": features}));
```