# Converting h3 hex id to polygon in python

Tags: python, geospatial, h3

I'm trying to take a h3 hex id and convert it to a polygon to use in a geodataframe (and eventually export as a shapefile). All of the methods in h3 documented online don't seem to work for me, and cannot figure out what method to use.

I'm using h3 3.7.6

```
import h3
h3.cells_to_multi_polygon('86264c28fffffff', geo_json=False)
```

gives me `AttributeError: module 'h3' has no attribute 'cells_to_multi_polygon'` (reference: https://h3geo.org/docs/api/regions/)

```
import h3
h3.h3_to_geo_boundary('86264c28fffffff', geo_json=False)
```

gives me `AttributeError: module 'h3' has no attribute 'h3_to_geo_boundary'` (reference: [How to generate shapefiles for H3 hexagons in a particular area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159241/how-to-generate-shapefiles-for-h3-hexagons-in-a-particular-area))

```
import h3
h3.cells_to_polygons('86264c28fffffff')
```

gives me `AttributeError: module 'h3' has no attribute 'cells_to_polygons'` (reference: https://uber.github.io/h3-py/api_reference.html#h3.cells_to_polygons)

those are the three methods that I've seen used in other posts (see references), none of these exist in the most recent version of h3 and I cannot figure out the correct one to use

Comment: See the answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382110

Answer (score 0):

Which version of h3 do you have? Maybe it is lower version of h3.

Try to install h3 latest version (4.0+).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).